# ASP.NET MVC 1-to-1 relationships: Can never get the edit action to work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I've tried this many different ways and have read many posts here on SO BUT...I'm missing something.  I'm used to ActiveRecord and similar approaches so EF is quite new to me.

I'm trying to do a simple Customer -> PhysicalAddress

Current error is a FK error

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property 
>   value(s)of 'Customer.CustomerId' on one end of a
>   relationship do not match the property value(s) of
>   'CustomerAddress.CustomerId' on the other end.

Debugging I can see that the PhysicalAddress is coming over with a CustomerId of 0.

Model:

```
public class Customer : EntityBase
{
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual CustomerAddress PhysicalAddress { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerAddress
{
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }  
    public string City { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Context:

```
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasKey(c => c.CustomerId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.PhysicalAddress)
            .WithRequired(a => a.Customer);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerAddress>()
            .HasKey(a => a.CustomerId);
    }
```

Controller Action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CustomerId,Name,PhysicalAddress,Active")] Customer customer)
{
    //customer.PhysicalAddress is null, Id 0.
    //
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified; //<--- Error here
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(customer);
}
```

I can tell that the 'customer' object passing into the action isn't fully setup.  I guess I need the extra nudge forward or something.

I've tried the Fluent API going both ways..from customer-> address and from address->customer.

I've tried stating the customer has an option address with many()

I've tried a hidden field in the edit view for model.PhysicalAddress.CustomerId

nothing seems to work!

Comment: I think the error is telling you that the CustomerAddress object does not have the same CustomerId in the parent object (Customer).  Inspect the `customer` object which is passed back in the Edit method and ensure that they both CustomerID's in Customer and PhysicalAddress are the same.

Comment: Yes - the problem is the 'CustomerId' on the address is coming over null - I dont know why or how to fix that, though.  I think that's the core problem.

Comment: Do you have "PhysicalAddress.CustomerId" as a hidden or some input in your form?

Comment: @tede24 adding model.PhysicalAddress.CustomerId clears the error and the data looks good in the debugger BUT - the changes to the address are not saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This operation should consider two details:

1. Your form should include the input PhysicalAddress.CustomerId to have that value set on your model when post, or even easier set manually CustomerId on your Edit action
2. Mark your PhysicalAddress entity as modified, as it is being attached as unmodified so it won't get updated

   ```
   db.Entry(customer.PhysicalAddress).State = EntityState.Modified;
   ```

Comment: I was about to tell you to write this answer as I figured out #2 5 minutes ago and It's working.  Thanks a lot!